# Why does http://localhost:3000/email/remind/1 takes me to http://localhost:3000/sessions/

Tags: email, session, ruby-on-rails-4, url

I am trying to send a login reminder from /session/new
When I submit the request I am taken to http://localhost:3000/email/remind/1 but the page shown is http://localhost:3000/sessions/
In routes.rb I have

```
get  'email/remind/:id' =>  'email#remind'
post 'email/remind/:id' => 'email#remind'
```

Can any body explain why I am being misdirected
[image: Screenshot showing /email/remind/1 in the address and /sessions/ on the screen]

From terminal

> Started GET "/email/remind/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-23 17:41:18
>   +0000 Processing by EmailController#remind as HTML   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}   ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session Load (0.1ms)  SELECT
>   "sessions".* FROM "sessions" WHERE "sessions"."session_id" = ?  ORDER
>   BY "sessions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["session_id",
>   "db283ddac9b9c0e1810541ad728398e2"]]   Rendered email/remind.html.erb
>   within layouts/application (0.6ms) Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views:
>   9.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)    (0.1ms)  begin transaction    (0.0ms)  commit transaction

Comment: Maybe you are requesting to have a user to be signed in?

Comment: There is no user, that is the problem. They have not signed in and created a session because they have forgotten the password. However the user exists so should be findable by email.

Comment: Can you post how the controller looks like?